# ActiveRecord select except columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way I can specify to select ALL columns in ActiveRecord except just a few. For example, for a User, I don't want to select their password hash or their email. Is this possible or do I have to manually hardcode all columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

write a scope like

```
def select_without columns
  select(column_names - columns.map(&:to_s))
end
```

Comment: I would do `def select_without *columns` so that you can take any number of arguments

Comment: There is an issue with this method: `COUNT` won't work here.
So, `Model.select([:a,:b]).count` will throw an error

Comment: What's `column_names` in this?

Comment: @bpromas `column_names` is a class method.

Comment: @VitalyDyatlov you can use `.size`. I am not an SQL expert but putting more than one column in the `select` will cause the error you are seeing. `COUNT` is pretty low level SQL. I believe you have to use a "window function" to make it work in this scenario. Something like `select *, count(*) over () as total_count from mytable`. In this case `size` works for me but I think there is some danger of it not being as accurate as `count` or `length`.

Comment: @wuliwong - `size` doesn't always work as a replacement for `count`. E.g. `ActiveRecord::Base.size` is not defined, since `size` is an `Enumerable` method. Also it will be slow with larger data-sets.

Answer (score 12):

Something like this?

```
exclude_columns = ['password', 'email']
columns = User.attribute_names.delete_if { |x| exclude_columns.include?(x) }

User.select(columns)
```

**EDIT**

I forgot that we can do **Array1 - Array2**

A best answer:

```
exclude_columns = ['password', 'email']
columns = User.attribute_names - exclude_columns

User.select(columns)
```

Comment: `delete_if` should have curly braces.

Answer (score 8):

Another really usefull way it's with a scope inside the model in case you need to avoid a column constantly.

In my case I save images into blob fields so I want to avoid those to be loaded everytime and in a easy way:

```
scope :select_exclude_image, ->  { select( Movie.attribute_names - ['image'] ) }
```

Then to avoid the image in the selection you can do something like that:

```
Movie.select_exclude_image.first
```

or

```
Movie.select_exclude_image.all
```

I hope it will help!

Comment: A more generic version, in ApplicationRecord, add:
`scope :select_except, ->(*excluded_columns) { select(attribute_names - excluded_columns.map(&:to_s)) }` -> `Movie.select_except(:image)`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add an option for people who want to exclude certain columns in every query by default can use the Rails 5 feature `ignored_columns`, which as the name suggests leaves those out.

The code is quite straightforward:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.ignored_columns = %w[password email]
end
```

Please note that the [ignore_columns documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-ignored_columns-3D) states that `You will get an error if accessing that attribute directly, so ensure all usages of the column are removed` so it may only work for cases where the columns are never required to be used.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, particularly when you're considering a `default_scope` to exclude certain columns, I would advise against this approach because of a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2541) with Rails about `count` breaking after a `select` clause. This can lead to surprising downstream errors.

In such a case, consider instead breaking your record into two tables, one with the essential data, the other one with the data you only need from time-to-time, then use associations to access the extra data.