# How to query a polymorphic associated relationship to return data from multiple tables - rails4

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have some tables that are joined through a polymorphic association...

I am trying to find a way to make a **single** query to return data from multiple of these tables...

My models are as follow:

```
#profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_profiles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wizards, through: :user_profiles, source: :user, source_type: "Wizard"
end

#user_profile.rb
class UserProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :profile
end

#wizard.rb
class Wizard < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_profile, as: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :profile, through: :user_profile
  has_one :wizard_specialization, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :career, through: :wizard_specialization
end

#career.rb
class Career < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wizard_specializations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wizards, through: :wizard_specializations
end
```

How can I write a join( or `:includes`) query to return the profile of **all** wizards, as well as their information from the `profiles` table, and also include their specialization from the `careers` table through the `wizard_specializations`?

Thanks in advance.

PS: It will be great if I can exclude fields like `created_at` & `updated_at`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord's `includes` method to [eager-load associated data](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). Combine that with the [`select`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) method to include or exclude just the columns that you want:

```
Wizard.includes(:career, :profile).select('wizards.name', 'wizards.etc', 'careers.name', 'careers.etc', 'profiles.*')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... how can I include data from the `profiles` table as well?

Comment: I can load something like this: `Wizard.includes(wizard_specialization: :career, user_profile: :profile)` but I can't select anything from any other table apart from the `wizards` table.

Comment: You should be able to do `Wizard.includes(:career, :profile)`. I think ActiveRecord will automatically traverse the `through` dependency and include the profile for that wizard.

Comment: FYI here's a SO question that explains how to exclude certain columns, which would be easier than writing out a list of included columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431028/activerecord-select-except-columns

Comment: Yes, I can do that... but the problem comes when I try to select... so `.select('wizards.id, wizards.name'...` works... but it breaks when I try to select from either `career` or `profile`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Rails has support for direct AR queries with all my setup configurations...

Anyways, I finally resolved to write it with pure SQL and execute with the help of:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

where `query` contains my pure SQL statement with the `SELECT`s and `JOIN`s and `WHERE`s